# Check a gpu memory periodically and run script when it gets free

Tags: python, bash

I have 4 GPUs (Nvidia) in my system. I want to check if a specific GPU is free (e.g. if the free memory is more than 10GB) periodically and if it is free I want to run a python script.

I think I can use nvidia-smi to check how much free memory I have for a given gpu. I have an idea but I couldn't complete the script completely. Is there anybody to help me ?

Here what I have written so far:

*check.sh*

```
id=$1
free_mem=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv -i $id)
echo $free_mem # this prints out: memory.free [MiB] 1954 MiB
while [ $free_mem -lt 10000 ]
    free_mem=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv -i $id)
    sleep 5

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$id python run_python_file.py
```

I believe the code should be something similar to the snippet above however I couldn't find out the  details.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: Well first of all, I guess `free_mem` keeps not only the free memory in GB but also some more information (when I echo free_mem variable I saw free.mem 1012 GB as output). Moreover I don't know if I should convert it to integer (somehow?) before comparing it with anotheri nteger in the condition of while loop

Comment: @sergio I added the content of `free_mem`

Answer (score 6):

Use `grep -Eo [0-9]+` to match one or more consecutive digits:

```sh
id=$1
free_mem=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv -i $id | grep -Eo [0-9]+)

while [ $free_mem -lt 10000 ]; do
    free_mem=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv -i $id | grep -Eo [0-9]+)
    sleep 5
done

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$id python run_python_file.py
```

An alternative to grep would be to use a [POSIX regex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html): `sed 's/[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/'`.

Comment: for zsh, use `grep -Eo "[0-9]+"`